# Users always have to press the google sign in button twice

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, button, google-play

I have a button for google sign in.

```
if (id == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            // start the asynchronous sign in flow
            mSignInClicked = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            boolean mAutoStartSignInFlow = true;
            builder1.dismiss();


        }
```

but everytime, a new user wants to log in, he has to press it twice: the first time, he can choose which account he wants to use, but it's not showing the Welcome player(with the level of the player and so on). the second time it actually logs him in, with that toast-thing from google on the top of the screen 'logged in Welcome player(with the level of the player and so on)'

how can I do that he only have to press once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the first time, he can choose which account he wants to use. the second time it actually logs him in,

If user has multiple accounts on device, Account Manager will ask for which one user wants to use.

You can save the token on device and next time user revisits your app, he won't be taken through this entire process, if token is valid.

Comment: how to do this? and, how do, that also the first time he logs in he just has to press it once, then the account manager pops up and after that it logs him in, without pressing the log in btn again?

Comment: Thanks @blockwala. I appreciate your effort for helping. If you think my question contributes towards SO, please concider to upvote it!